# Call a vector's function given the vector's pointer as a void *

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am working on implementing a game engine using ECS principles as an excercise. My current design has a ComponentManager class that is to store all the vectors that correspond to each component type. A minimal version of the class looks like this:

```
class ComponentManager{
private:
    std::vector<void*> componentHolder;

public:
    bool destroyEntity(int entityID, componentSignature toDestroy);

    template <class T>
    int registerComponent();
    template <class T>
    bool addComponent(int entity, T initialComp);
    template <class T>
    bool removeComponent(int entity);
};
```

The componentHolder is a vector of void* where each entry is the vector containing a different component type. The reason I am doing this is because I want to store all the components in contiguous memory, however each component is a different type. If I was to use a vector of pointers to some base component class, that would defeat the cache coherence, data-flow oriented benefits that I am trying to exploit with this ECS engine.

Also, My engine is designed so that others can create custom components by simply defining a struct containing the data they wish that component to store and registering that component on the creation of a new game "world" (or instance if you prefer). This registration is done via the registerComponent() function seen above, creating a unique id for each component type, and is defined as:

```
template <class T> 
int ComponentManager::registerComponent(){
    componentHolder.push_back(new std::vector<T>);
    return type_id<T>();
}
```

The type_id() function is a trick I found from [this stackexchange question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48594/unique-type-id-no-rtti?noredirect=1&lq=1) and is what allows me to map the component types to integers which I use as indices in the ComponentManager vector. This has worked well for the creation/access of components, as those functions are templates and get the type of the component passed in (and as a result I can static cast the void* that is at the index of the componentHolder vector to the right type), here's an example of this:

```
template <class T>
bool ComponentManager::addComponent(int entityID){
    int compID = type_id<T>();
    std::vector<T>* allComponents = (std::vector<T>*)componentHolder[compID];

    if (compEntityID.find(entityID) == compEntityID.end()){
        (*allComponents).push_back(T());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

however the issue comes from when I want to destroy an entity entirely. My function for destroying an entity simply requires the entity ID, and the component signature (a bitset that has bits flipped to 1 corresponding to which components this entity has) which is stored in the gameWorld object and is passed in. However, since the destroyEntity function does not get types passed into it via template functions, and only has the bitset to know which type of component to destroy, I can't figure out a way to get the type so that I can cast the void* to the right vector. Here is an example of what I want the destroyEntity function to do:

```
bool ComponentManager::destroyEntity(int entityID, componentSignature toDestroy){
for (int x = 0; x < MAX_COMPONENT; x++){
    if (toDestroy[x]){
        std::vector<??>* allComponents = (std::vector<??>*)componentHolder[x];  // Here is where the issue lies
            (*allComponents).erase((*allComponents).begin() + entityIndex); 
        }               
    }
}
```

Is there a way during component registration for example that I could store a function pointer to each vector's erase method that I could later call from the destroyEntity() function? Or some way to store a map from the integer componentID I create during registration to the type itself, and use that later to cast? The types of components that are in the game will be known at run time, so I feel like this should be doable somehow? Also as a caveat there is some additional logic I have to figure out which entity owns which component in each component vector in componentHolder that I omitted for brevity, so that won't be causing any issues.

Thank you in advanced for your help/any tips you can provide! I appreciate you reading through this long post, and I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class...Ts>
using operation = void(*)(void* t, void*state, Ts...);

template<class...Ts>
struct invoker{
  operation<Ts...> f;
  std::shared_ptr<void> state;
  void operator()(void* t, Ts...ts)const{
    f(t, state.get(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};
template<class T, class...Ts, class F>
invoker<Ts...> make_invoker(F&& f){
  return {
    [](void* pt, void* state, Ts...ts){
      auto* pf=static_cast<std::decay_t<F>*>(state);
      (*pf)( *static_cast<T*>(pt), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
    },
    std::make_shared<std::decay_t<F>>( std::forward<F>(f) )
  };
}
```

so how does this help?  Well you can store howto erase by index using this.

```
    std::vector<??>* allComponents = (std::vector<??>*)componentHolder[x];  // Here is where the issue lies
        (*allComponents).erase((*allComponents).begin() + entityIndex);
```

what you want is a `f(void*, int)` that does the above.

```
template<class T>
invoker<int> erase_at_index(){
  return make_invoker<std::vector<T>,int>([]( auto&&vec, int index ){
    vec.erase(vec.begin()+index);
  };
}
```

simply store `std::vector<invoker<int>> erasers;`.  When a new type is added , push a new eraser made by `erase_at_index<T>`.

Then:

```
    erasers[x](componentHolder[x],entityIndex);
```

and done.

The shared ptr is once per type; if that overhead is too much, aligned storage and static asserts that the F isn't too big can be used instead.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for this answer! Would you mind explaining what is going on in the invoker<> struct (or pointing me to some resources that describe how it works)? Is this a sort of well known design pattern that I can read more on? Or is this sort of thing generally something you want to avoid?

Comment: @The_O_King It is a kind of type erasure.  Here I'm using templates write C-style `void*` and function pointer type erasure.  I also use the shared ptr's type erasure of destruction to handle lifetime issues.